# Saving user images - reaching maximum folder limit

Tags: php, image

I'm using ext3 and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Functionality), the maximum sub directories allowed is around 32000. Currently, each user is given their own directory to upload images on the filesystem. This makes it simple to retrieve images and ease of access. the folder structure is like this:

```
../images/<user id>/<image>
../images/<another user id>/<image>
```

I don't want to commit to a design that is doomed to fail with scalability, specifically when 32k users have upload images. While this may never be achieved, I still think it is bad practice.

Does anyone have an idea to avoid this problem? I would prefer not to use the database if possible for reasons of unnecessary queries and speed.

Comment: This limit is per directory. If you have dir A with max 32k subdirs, the subdir A/B may have 32k entries, A/B/C may have 32k entries too, as well as A/C may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subdirectory for when the previous one gets full

```
/images/<a>/<user id 1>/<image>
/images/<a>/<user id 2>/<image>
...
/images/<a>/<user id 32000>/<image>
/image/<b>/<user id 32001>/<image>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I was looking for. If I ever get to the point that the directory `images` needs to be split up, the website would be the least of my worries!

Answer (score 2):

You could have a multi-level hierarchy, where each level is guaranteed to never exceed the maximum.

For example, if your user ids are defined with the regular expression [A-Za-z0-9_]+, you have 64 possible choices for any given character (I'm adding a space to account for spaces at the end when ids are shorter). Taking two characters together you have 64*64 = 4096 total possibilities. You cannot do three characters as that takes you over your limit. Then with this info you can create the directories by splitting the ids in groups of two letters. Example: user ids "miguel" and "miguel12345" would go to:

```
/images/mi/gu/el/<image>
/images/mi/gu/el/12/34/5/<image>
```

Note how the last component can be one char long if the length of the id is odd. This is fine, since the space is accounted as a possible char, you will still be within the max sub-directory limit.

Good luck!

Comment: While this would work, I think William Van Rensselaer is the most practical and easiest solution. Both of your answers were getting at the same point, which is to force each directory to never have more than 32000 sub directories. As a side note, the user IDs are integers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i'm getting this right and this ir some sort of web app You could use some abstract layer to imitate that folder structure and save the files in one directory. save file real name in database, and save uploaded file with some unique name. then list users files from database.